# Type resolution in function

Tags: typescript

I can't figure why this is failing as Type seems to be resolve this ok, but function returns are not really happy for it.
So if T have undefined then return should be undefined or DataObject, else it's DataObject

```js
    type DataObject<T> = { data: T };
    
    type FlatDataObject<T> = T extends undefined ? undefined : DataObject<NonNullable<T>>
    
    function builder<T>(value: T): FlatDataObject<T> {
        if (value === undefined) {
            return undefined;
        }
        return {
            data: value,
        }
    }
    
    const demo1 = builder<string>('asd');
    const demo2 = builder<string | undefined>('asd');
```

[TS sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOB5ARgKwgY2AHgCoB8UAvFAN5QAmCcAXFHlAL4DcAUG6JFAGIA2CeIlQZs%20IqUYQAHsAgA7SgGcoAV0UQAZgEt5ESlAD8ajTr0H6Q5Oiy4AcgHt5d1XwEo%20EcQQ6b12bScoFFVtPkoIACdxAAoANzg%20VQh6PABKen5BGhFbcXI2KCKobU0oeMTkkmJSdQizfTSC4paoSIhgVUj5E3rdfXYWpkLi9s7u5tai6kR6BKSIABoRouHhtkwnJWAqCABbBwBGEmDQ8KicbcjdAHMCGIByOCVKB7T2Tflt3YOAJhOQmEItErrcoAAfXpafqUe5PF5vFhAA)

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use a type assertion to tell TypeScript that the return type of the function is indeed `FlatDataObject<T>`.

```js
// ...rest of code

function builder<T>(value: T): FlatDataObject<T> {
    if (value === undefined) {
        return undefined as FlatDataObject<T>; // <--- notice this
    }
    return {
        data: value,
    } as FlatDataObject<T>; // <--- and this
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOB5ARgKwgY2AHgCoB8UAvFAN5QAmCcAXFHlAL4DcAUG6JFAGIA2CeIlQZs+IqUYQAHsAgA7SgGcoAV0UQAZgEt5ESlAD8ajTr0H6Q5Oiy4AcgHt5d1XwEo+EcQQ6b12bScoFFVtPkoIACdxAAoANzg+VQh6PABKen5BGhFbcXI2KCKobU0oeMTkkmJSdQizfTSC4paoSIhgVUj5E3rdfSg4FSzgK1yxQnYWpkLi9s7u5tai6kR6BKSIABpZoqZB4YFRnJsJgnYZtkwnJWAqCABbBwBGEmDQ8KicW8jdAHMCDEAORDShAtLsa7yW73J4AJjeITCEWiP3+UAAPr0tP1KICQUowRCgA)

Comment: just wonderinig why TS can't solve those as undefined is valid for return type and same as object with data?